# Why the GND is visible for 2 layer design in PADS layout?

Tags: layout, pcb-layers, via, mentor-pads

I am facing an error while practicing a reference design of the DLP-2232M-G board downloaded from Mentor's website.

The design engineer of this board has used 2 layer (TOP and BOTTOM ) keeping 3 to 21th layer inactive.
Take a look " layer setup", in both case he assigned GND at "Assign Nets".

[image: 2_layer]

After I made schematic in PADS logic and connect with PADS layout, I found that a GND trace exists in the PADS layout design.

Take a look, 2 capacitors ends are shorted, they should be "GND". In this design, no layer for "GND" has been called.

[image: gnd]

If you feel any setting is necessary in "Design rules", let me know.

Comment: You don't always need a GND layer, if you're making a cheap board or want to keep it single sided then using traces for GND is fine in most applications

Comment: Need to be more specific on PADS design setting/ display setting, this design contains routed path on both side. gnd traces has appeared on what I am doing.

Comment: Is there a GND net on the actual schematic?

Comment: Yes, it has. "Off-pages" are also available.

Comment: If GND is a net on the actual schematic then when it has been pulled over for PCB layout then it will expect tracks to connect the different parts of the net, hence the yellow guide lines. I think the confusion you're making is that GND must be it's own separate layer. You can put whichever tracks you want on whichever layer you want.

Comment: If so, then there might be setting in PADS logic what I am skipping.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the PADS logic. Eagle does the exact same thing, I'm not quite sure what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I do appreciate your instructions.
Sudden tricks came in my mind, that was very common setting.

To invisible GND tracks, View>Nets> View nets dialog box will appear, select GND from the net list and add it in View list.
After that, unchecked the View Details ( Trace plus the following un-routes ) option.

Comment: If this is your solution you need to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with it. Just connect all the ground using bottom layer using copper pour function. Highlight it green by going into Nets function [CTRL + Shift + N]

Comment: Yes, it might be alternative solution. Using key board things going to be more easy.